# How to get the number of bytes actually occupied by a string in memory?

Tags: c++, string, memory, optimization, stl

As far as I know, there is implementation-dependent `string` optimization in C++ which lets the `string` not to allocate any additional heap memory to store its characters, but rather store the characters in the `string` object itself. So if the string `s` allocates additional memory on the heap, the total memory it consumes is `sizeof(string) + s.capacity()`, however, if it does not allocate any additional memory on the heap, i.e. stores its characters in the `string` object, then the total memory consumption is `sizeof(string)`.

Is there a way to figure out this quantity - the total memory consumed by a string? The problem is that I don't see a way to figure out whether a string object has allocated memory on the heap or not, so I don't know which formula to use for a certain `string`.

EDIT: a hack injecting something in STL namespace to figure out the implementation-dependent detail (the threshold at which a `string` starts to allocate additional memory) would be ok if there is no other solution.

Comment: I would think that if you really need to know one way or the other then you probably shouldn't be relying on the implementation of `std::string`. You could always write your own allocator.

Comment: As a cheeky trick you could check if `s.data()` is similar to `&s`...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think you should post that as an answer: like `(const char*)&s <= s.data() && s.data() <= (const char*)((&s)+1)`.

Comment: You need to be careful, pointers cannot be order-compared in general. It's a bit subtle.

Comment: Before C++11 std::string used to share buffer after copying a string variable to another variable. The buffer is actually allocated (and copied from original buffer) when one of the linked strings is modified (copy-on-write). Therefore the calculation should take this into account.

Comment: @Serge Rogatch Please check my other answer where I use allocation hook in GCC. This should  works for any allocation.

Comment: In the heap storage case, there will almost certainly be an additional char for null termination. Moreover, "total memory consumed" suggests to me that you also need to count any overhead of operator new, which may be substantial.

Comment: @DesertFish, `string::capacity()` should account for null-terminator. There is overhead for alignment, because e.g. `new char[1]` actually allocates the character at an 8-byte aligned address.

Comment: @Serge Rogatch. No, capacity() does not include any null-terminator. And that's a good thing since it's obviously not counted for size().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `s.data()` points to the first character of the string, you can check whether that address lies within the string object itself.

Make sure to use equality-comparison only, since pointers to objects that are not subobjects of the same complete object do not have a specified ordering. Moreover, you cannot use pointer arithmetic, which is only allowed for pointers into a given array, and you don't know beforehand whether the data pointer lies inside the string object.

For example:

```
bool data_is_inline(const std::string & s)
{
    const char * p = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&s), * q = s.data();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(s); ++i)
        if (p + i == q) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vav3dRr3VmZitPXG) (try different compilers).

Comment: Remark: Funny things will happen with libstdc++ < 5.0: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HVB8wm6lvLLKb6yF http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5Lh8gk7GYZvWJ5js In the second link one can see that the strings share the memory, so the question how much space either of them uses becomes somewhat weird.

Comment: Still the solution with pointer comparison is tempting because it's faster than iteration over the whole `string` object, which is 32 bytes on MSVC++2013 release so 32 iterations are saved in case the characters are stored out of `string` object.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: Have you measured the difference in performance?

Comment: @KerrekSB But the release of gcc5 not so much. Don't get me wrong, I upvoted this answer, but as gcc4.x is still widely used I felt like making people aware of this is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload global **malloc** function and **::operator new** and add the requested size to some global variable. Then you can subtract total allocated count before and after creating or modifying the string.

```
size_t before = getTotalAllocated();
std::string str("Hello!");
size_t after = getTotalAllocated();
size_t diff = afer - before;
```

You can add sizeof(std::string) to diff if you like

Comment: This won't work if `::operator new` does not use `malloc`

Comment: Perhaps replace global new as well? This is just general idea.

Comment: Once could imagine `std::string` having its own allocator

Comment: This solution is problematic in a multi-threaded program. Also, it is hard to stick to the possibility to call something both before and after string construction: I am in a situation when I need a function which receives a ready string and returns its total memory consumption.

Comment: If this is a real project requirement (not an academic issue), you may consider using the custom allocator in the std::string. Also you can roll your own string class as well if you know what you want to achieve. Before C++11 we thought about designing our own string class because std::string shares allocated buffer and do copy on write, which sometimes had catastrophic effect on our multithreaded program.

Answer (score 1):

> So if the string `s` allocates additional memory on the heap, the total memory it consumes is `sizeof(string) + s.capacity()`, however, if it does not allocate any additional memory on the heap, i.e. stores its characters in the string object, then the total memory consumption is `sizeof(string)`.

I believe you cannot make the distinction without diving into implementation specific details (different on Linux/GCC `libstdc++` and on Windows...). And the standard does not require (even if it highly probable) to just spend `sizeof(string) + s.capacity()` in the bad case (perhaps some `std::string` implementations could spend more memory).

AFAIK, many implementations deal differently with "short" strings and with "long" ones, the threshold being an implementation specific detail.

The standard does not prohibit `std::string` to use some own specific allocator, doing some [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) -even if that is unlikely-, or whatever

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how to use allocation hook to measure string allocation with GCC compiler.

Please note there are other hooks that may be interesting like `realloc` and `free`.

Here is the reference: [Hooks for malloc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html)

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void my_init_hook (void);
static void *my_malloc_hook (size_t, const void *);
void* (* old_malloc_hook)(size_t size, const void *caller);
void (* volatile  __malloc_initialize_hook) (void) = my_init_hook;

static void my_init_hook (void)
{
  old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;
  __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
}

size_t g_counter = 0;

static void * my_malloc_hook (size_t size, const void *caller)
{
    g_counter += size;
    __malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;
    cout << "Allocated: " << size << endl;
    void* result =  malloc(size);
    __malloc_hook = my_malloc_hook;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "*** On stack ***" << endl;
    string a("12345");
    string b("1234567890");
    string c("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
    string d(c);
    d[1] = 'A'; // this makes big allocation!
    cout << "*** On heap ***" << endl;
    string* x = new string("1234567890");
    string* y = new string(*x);
    string* z = new string(*x);
    cout << "Total allocation:" << g_counter << endl; 
}
```

The result is:

```
*** On stack ***
Allocated: 18
Allocated: 23
Allocated: 63
Allocated: 63
*** On heap ***
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 23
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4
Total allocation:202
```

You can verify that line `d[1] = 'A';` makes another allocation of 63 bytes.

This can be improved to count the allocation which originates only from specific caller, e.g. string allocator or to make allocation statistics by caller. I've dome something similar a long time ago to find out who is allocating strings, but I used the method of unwinding the stack.